# How to write composer.json while my own system is a vendor?

Tags: php, json, twig, composer-php, slim

I've started learning composer and I am trying to build a composer.json file where I want to put all my base classes (i.e. a custom framework) as a vendor itself with other dependencies.

The scenario is that I am building a small framework with Slim, Twig and Laravel ORM etc and I want to put my framework (with all of it's dependencies) in a folder outside of the document root as it can be used for several projects by a custom PHP included path either set in PHP.ini or by set_include_path(). I am using a VPS.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/path/to/my/own/framework
 |----> composer.json
 |----> composer.lock
 |----> vendor
         |----> slim
         |----> illuminate
         |----> twig
         |----> om
                 |----> OmFramework (this is my own framework)
                          |----> Factory
                                  |----> BaseController.php
 ....
```

I have written the following composer.json so far:

```
{
    "name": "....",
    "description": "....",
    "keywords": ["..."],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            ....
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">= 5.3.0",
        "slim/slim": "2.4.*",
        "slim/views":"0.1.2",
        "twig/twig": "1.*",
        "twig/extensions": "*",
        "itsgoingd/slim-facades": "dev-master",
        "illuminate/database" : "4.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry" : "2.*",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "1.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "OmFramework": "." }
    }
}
```

What should I write into the autoload section in order to load all my classes from om/OmFramework through the composer.json file? Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

The BaseController.php file:

```
<?php
namespace OmFramework\Factory;

class BaseController {
        public function __construct()
        {
                //TO-DO:
        }

        public function sayHello() 
        {
                echo 'Hello World!' . "\n";
        }
}
```

If I have missed any information that would help you to guide me, I will be happy to share those.

Please note that I am developing the framework locally and not using github for now. When it is ready, I will push it to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework package should ship it's own code in a directory of choice (excluding the vendor directory itself), and then point the autoloader definition to it:

```
/path/to/my/own/framework
 |----> composer.json
 |----> composer.lock
 |----> om
 |------> OmFramework
 |---------> Factory
 |------------> BaseController.php
 |----> vendor
         |----> slim
         |----> illuminate
         |----> twig
```

The "autoload" section of the composer.json will be simple:

```
{
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "OmFramework\\": "om/OmFramework"
       } 
   }
}
```

PSR-4 is preferred to be used when dealing with namespaced classes. PSR-0 should be used for older classes without namespaces.

Comment: The first solution is not feasible because you don't commit the vendor folder, so you cannot point the autoloader there because there will be no files coming from the current framework package. The correct way would be to create a framework package, and if a project want's to use it, it creates a new `composer.json` and adds the dependency for it. Automatically your framework will be under `vendor`, but for this project only, not when developing your framework. Composer will adjust the path correctly.

Comment: @Sven I understand and completely agree with you. Thanks for your guidance.